# BindingSource Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.DateTime and System.String

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to filtre a datagridview using a searchbox , I have a function that works great with strings but I don't know why I get an exception when I use this function with a column that contains int/date values :

```
 public void SearchTable(TextBox searchBox, String columnNameToSearch, int Type)
    {
        BindingSource bs;
        switch (Type)
        {
            case NUMERIC_COLUMN:
                bs = new BindingSource
                {
                    DataSource = _dgv.DataSource,
                    Filter = columnNameToSearch + " = " + searchBox.Text.Trim()
                };
                _dgv.DataSource = bs;
                break;
            case TEXT_COLUMN:
                bs = new BindingSource
                {
                    DataSource = _dgv.DataSource,
                    Filter = columnNameToSearch + " LIKE '" + searchBox.Text.Trim() + "%'"
                };
                _dgv.DataSource = bs;
                break;
        }
    }
```

this is the exception :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU1Xr.png

When I try the query in SQL server the query works

Comment: DateTime are a numeric type - you cant do LIKE with numbers.  Is 1 LIKE 10?  use something along the lines of > or <

Comment: I used "=" doesn't work for me I get : Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.Int32.

Comment: assuming the column to search is actually a DateTime type, you are going to have to convert what is in the `searchBox` to the same type. Use DateTime.TryParse()...

Comment: Thank you so much after searching I missed ' ' in the filter , thank you !